# I'm having JavaScript issues making an API call and receiving the JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, get

I'm hosting a RESTful API on localhost that when run in a browser, returns something like this:

```
{ 
  "ContactMethod": "Email",
  "Zip": "68504",
  "State": "Illinois",
  "LastName": "McCarthy",
  "BestTimes": "Afternoon",
  "Address": {
    "Zip": "68504",
    "State": "Illinois",
    "City": "Haylon",
    "Line1": "1388 Dooleys Terrace",
    "Line2": "",
    "Line3": ""
  },
  "BestDays": "Wednesday",
  "FirstName": "Roy",
  "Email": "rmccarthy@yah00.com",
  "Phone": "4812212563"
}
```

I can request either plain text or application JSON. My API is using this type of JSON: http://json.org/example. **Please note that the above is mocked data and nobody's actual contact information.**

I have a widget written in JavaScript and jQuery 1.11.3, and I'd like it to make a GET request and consume the JSON response.

I've tried this:

```
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
};

getJSON('myurl').then(function(data) {
  alert(data.result);
```

The alert never occurs. I've tried this, from here: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp

```
function getUserDetails(){
  var request = new XMLHttpReqest();
  var url = "myurl";

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      var myArr = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      alert(myArr);
    }
  }
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.send();
}
```

That `alert(myArr)` never occurs, so something must be wrong with the request, right? I don't get the alert when I try this either:

```
function getUserDetails(){
  $.getJSON("myurl", function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
        alert(field);
    })
  });
}
```

I've also tried throwing in `jQuery.parseJSON()` here and there, with no luck. My team is trying to complete something that a coworker wasn't able to finish before leaving, and none of us know much about JavaScript. We'd appreciate any help we can get!

EDIT1: Upon suggestions from the comments, I checked the request in Chrome DevTools. The status was 200 OK.

[image]

EDIT2: Using this, we were able to get an alert that read `[object Object]`.

```
function getUserDetails(){
  var data = $.getJSON("myurl");
  //var obj = $.JSON.parse(data);
  //var obj = eval ("(" + data + ")");
  alert(data);
  return data;
}
```

In the widget, it's giving us some gibberish:

[image]

So that's closer, right? When we implement either of the commented out lines, it goes back to not working.

Comment: Press F12, and go to the networking tab. Refresh the page/do your javascript call again, and make sure you're getting back a 200 request.

Comment: Have you tried checking the network tab in DevTools (in Chrome or Firefox)? That should at least tell you whether the request completes.

Comment: Check the console to see if any request is actually happening, and also try adding `.catch` to your promise, in case of rejection.

Comment: As you only ever `alert` for success, the request is obviously failing - as the first three comments suggest, check the console

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Yes, the status on the request is 200 OK.

Comment: If either of the above statements about using the network tab don't make sense to you, in the `getUserDetails` function move the `alert` to above the `$.each` and alert the `result` to indicate if you are getting a response body at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning an array. So, the $.each makes no sense.

Try this:

```
var url = "your_url";

function getUserDetails(){
  $.getJSON(url, function(result){
        alert(result);
  })
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
})
  .always(function() {alert( "complete" );});
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful. It's showing the "error" and "complete" alerts. How do you think I should go about troubleshooting? I know that the API response status is 200 OK, and that it's returning valid JSON.

Comment: Well, it is very unlikely that you are getting a 200 status and getting the "error" alert. Can you post the Response Body that shows your developer tools in your browser.

Comment: I just updated the .fail method. That should show you more details.

Comment: On your first suggestion, without the updated .fail method, both the "error" and "complete" alerts were showing. With your updated .fail method, only the "complete" alert shows. In developer tools, it's showing the status as 200 OK, but under the response tab, it says "This request has no response data available." When the URL is typed into a browser,  the response viewed in the developer tools is valid JSON.

Comment: I am sorry. Can you change this: "console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
" with this an alert like this: "alert( "Request Failed: " + err );" and see if it shows something.

Comment: It's showing this: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load (myurl). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." So the widget and the web service are on different domains. That makes sense.

Comment: OK, so, if they are in different domains then you have a different situation here :) I would really appreciate if you can Accept my answer as it helped you show the alerts which is what you were looking for in the first place and now it led you to find your actual response.

Comment: You're right, different issue. Thanks so much for your help!